# Nuget warning 1601: all is good, but here is a warning anyways. How does it make sense?

Tags: nuget

I get this warning:

> Common.fsproj: [NU1601] Dependency specified was AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 (>= 3.7.0.8) but ended up with AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 3.7.0.30.

so the dependency specified was **>=** 3.7.0.8
and it got version 3.7.0.30

since 3.7.0.30 >= 3.7.0.8, why the warning? not to mention that "Dependency specified" doesn't say specified by what...